# Add server side errors to form in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following Angular 7 Component:

```
export class SendMessageComponent implements OnInit { 

  message: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.message = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      name: ['', Validators.required], 
      email: [''], 
      message: ['']
    });

  }

  onSubmit() {

    if (this.message.valid) {

      this.messageService.send(message).subscribe(

        (successResponse: SuccessResponse>) => { },

        (errorResponse) => {

          if (errorResponse.status === 400) {

            for (var error in errorResponse.error.errors) {

            }

          }            

        },

      );

    }

  }

}
```

When there are errors the server returns `errorResponse.error.errors` which is something like:

```
[
  { name: "Email", info: "Email is unavailable" }
]
```

I would like to add the server side errors to my form.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setErrors()` method on the form control you want to add the error to.

e.g, for your email field:

`this.message.get('email').setErrors({ error: 'A server side error' });`

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hq4p43

For your use-case, you can do it your loop, so long as your server returns the same `Name` as your `FormGroup` controls.

```
for (let error in errorResponse.error.errors) {
   this.message.get(error.name.toLowerCase()).setErrors({ error: error.info });
}
```

More info: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors

Answer (score 1):

You can call FormControl's setErrors() method to achieve this.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors